# How to get the Bundle object which represents a fragment bundle?

Tags: eclipse, osgi, osgi-bundle, osgi-fragment

I tried the following code in the fragment bundle

`Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle( getClass() ) ;`

but the **bundle** object still represents the **host** bundle, how to get the Bundle object representing the **fragment** bundle ?

Comment: You can use `Platform.getBundle(String)` to get bundles by their id.

Comment: What problem does that solve?

Comment: @greg-449  Is that "org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.getBundle(String)" ? The parameter is the symbolic name of the bundle. But how to get the symbolic name of the bundle dynamically ?

Comment: @nitind To find some resources in a fragment bundle and maybe have the same name as the resources in the host bundle.

Comment: I don't think you can have the same name in the main plugin and fragment and access them both.

Answer (score 1):

Classes are always loaded by the host bundle. So it is not possible to get a Bundle object for a fragment which contains a class using `FrameworkUtil.getBundle(Class)`.

Given the host Bundle object, you can then find the attached fragments. See https://docs.osgi.org/specification/osgi.core/8.0.0/framework.wiring.html#d0e13920.